# Simple Spring, use of ClasspathApplicationContext for standalone apps, how to reuse?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, inversion-of-control, cron

If I have a standalone main application.  Say 20 classes.  They all may need to interface with the beans defined by the spring configuration (ApplicationContext) at any time.  I would bootstrap the classpath application context at the main application entry point.  But how do you reuse the already instantiated beans?

For example, it seems like a bad approach to setup the ClasspathApplicationContext as a singleton, but that would be the idea.

I thought I had seen a GlobalContextLocator or something along those lines but didn't seen an example on how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it.  Your best reference is here:

http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-introduction

and the specific classes you need to look at are SingletonBeanFactoryLocator and ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.

If you use the SingletonBeanFactoryLocator you can use the following to look up beans:

```
BeanFactoryLocator bfl = SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.getInstance();
BeanFactoryReference bf = bfl.useBeanFactory("com.mycompany.myapp");
MyClass zed = bf.getFactory().getBean("mybean");
```

There is a very good explanation of this in detail in the Javadocs:

http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/access/SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.html

Also, just to be clear, make sure that the config file is in your classpath for your application, otherwise the lookup will fail.